# Regular expression: ignore lines begining with these characters

Tags: regex, grep, whitespace

How do you create a regular expression to ignore lines beginning with "empty character", #, or letter. Below is a sample of the data I have and I need to match the lines starting with numbers only (negative or positive):

```
0.000000    1.2712052472 0.8899021956 22.2458  265.2511402076  322.1539247218 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000227
0.000000    1.2712052462 0.8899021922 22.2458  265.2511430964  322.1539209801 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000090
0.000000    1.2712052476 0.8899022047 22.2458  265.2511396341  322.1539260295 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000111
0.000000    1.2712052465 0.8899022229 22.2458  265.2511497521  322.1539197205 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000059
Nplanets 9  Nparticles 500: alive 509/509  ejected 0  rmin 0  rmax 0
Full close app checks 0/0 (0.000000%)   BS fails 0
Close apps 1   bounces 0   accretions 0  Max n/step 0
Simulation time 0 going to -100000.
Real time 1 s   Force  0 s (0.00 %)   Coll 0 s  (0.00 %)
               E&L    0 s (0.00 %)    Kep 0 s (0.00 %)
CPU time 0.037627 s   Force  0 s (0.00 %)   Coll 0 s  (0.00 %)
               E&L     0 s (0.00 %)  Kep 0 s (0.00 %)
# Nplanets 9  Nparticles 500: alive 509/509  ejected 0  rmin 0  rmax 0
# Full close app checks 0/0 (0.000000%)   BS fails 0
# Close apps 1   bounces 0   accretions 0  Max n/step 0
# Simulation time 0 going to -100000.
# Real time 1 s   Force  0 s (0.00 %)   Coll 0 s  (0.00 %)
#                E&L    0 s (0.00 %)    Kep 0 s (0.00 %)
# CPU time 0.037627 s   Force  0 s (0.00 %)   Coll 0 s  (0.00 %)
#                E&L     0 s (0.00 %)  Kep 0 s (0.00 %)
Output step 1 at t=-10 going to -100000
-10.000000    1.2713031501 0.8900442847 22.1802  265.4033924020  322.0041354013 -5.32091 -102.357 0.155286 0.88482 phaet_000065
-10.000000    1.2713031508 0.8900443093 22.1802  265.4033954804  322.0041360861 -5.32091 -102.357 0.155286 0.88482 phaet_000299
-10.000000    1.2713031483 0.8900442977 22.1802  265.4033839221  322.0041469420 -5.32092 -102.357 0.155286 0.88482 phaet_000102
-10.000000    1.2713031486 0.8900442931 22.1802  265.4033724632  322.0041581369 -5.32092 -102.357 0.155286 0.884821 phaet_000371
-10.000000    1.2713031463 0.8900442910 22.1802  265.4033772870  322.0041532421 -5.32093 -102.357 0.155286 0.884821 phaet_000019
```

I want to finally have:

```
0.000000    1.2712052472 0.8899021956 22.2458  265.2511402076  322.1539247218 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000227
0.000000    1.2712052462 0.8899021922 22.2458  265.2511430964  322.1539209801 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000090
0.000000    1.2712052476 0.8899022047 22.2458  265.2511396341  322.1539260295 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000111
0.000000    1.2712052465 0.8899022229 22.2458  265.2511497521  322.1539197205 -13.6281 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000059
-10.000000    1.2713031501 0.8900442847 22.1802  265.4033924020  322.0041354013 -5.32091 -102.357 0.155286 0.88482 phaet_000065
-10.000000    1.2713031508 0.8900443093 22.1802  265.4033954804  322.0041360861 -5.32091 -102.357 0.155286 0.88482 phaet_000299
-10.000000    1.2713031483 0.8900442977 22.1802  265.4033839221  322.0041469420 -5.32092 -102.357 0.155286 0.88482 phaet_000102
-10.000000    1.2713031486 0.8900442931 22.1802  265.4033724632  322.0041581369 -5.32092 -102.357 0.155286 0.884821 phaet_000371
-10.000000    1.2713031463 0.8900442910 22.1802  265.4033772870  322.0041532421 -5.32093 -102.357 0.155286 0.884821 phaet_000019
```

So, I tried "grep" as follows:

```
grep -v '^[a-z,A-Z,\s,\#]' file1.dat > file2.dat
```

It gets rid of the lines starting with letters and '#' but lines starting with a white space are still present, i.e I can't remove:

```
       E&L    0 s (0.00 %)    Kep 0 s (0.00 %)
       E&L     0 s (0.00 %)  Kep 0 s (0.00 %)
```

Note that there is white space preceding "E&L".

Any idea how to get rid of these too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grep, `[\s,\#]` matches a backslash, a comma, or a hash sign.  (Backslash has no special meaning in a bracket expression, and comma is never special.)  The easiest way to match whitespace is with the `[:space:]` character class.  So your regex would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z#[:space:]]
```

You could also do a positive search for lines that *do* start with numbers:

```
^-\?[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+
```

Comment: I think this solution is the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the leading white spaces these two lines will not eliminate.
You can eliminate them at first.

```
sed "s/^[ \t]*//" file1.dat > file3.dat
```

Then use 'grep' command for filtering the file.

```
grep -v '^[a-z,A-Z,\s,\#]' file3.dat > file2.dat
```